# Fill runtime azure pipeline parameters from external source

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We looking to create a pipeline to update our multi-tenant azure environment. We need to perform some actions during the update per tenant. To accomplish this, we would like to create a job per tenant, so we can process tenants in parallel. To accomplish this, I want to use a runtime parameter to pass the tenants to update to my pipeline as follows:

```
parameters:
- name: tenants
  type: object
```

the value of the tenants parameter might look like something like this:

```
- Name: "customer1"
  Someotherproperty: "some value"
- Name: "customer2"
  Someotherproperty: "some other value"
```

to generate the jobs, we do something like this:

```
stages:
- stage:
  jobs:
  - job: Update_Tenant
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ${{ each tenant in parameters.Tenants }}:
          ${{ tenant.tenantName }}:
            name: ${{ tenant.tenantName }}
            someproperty: ${{ tenant.otherProperty }}
      maxParallel: 2
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: echo $(name).$(someproperty)
```

Now what we need, is some way to fill this `tenants` parameter. Now I tried a few solutions:

- Ideally I would like to put a build stage before the `Update_Tenants` stage to call a REST api to get the tenants, and expand the `tenants` parameter when the `Update_Tenants` stage starts, but this is not supported AFAIK, since parameter expansion is done when the pipeline starts.
- A less ideal but still workable option would have been to create a variable group yaml file containing the tenants, and include this variable group in my pipeline, and use the `${{ variables.Tenants }}` syntax to reference them. However, for some reason, variables can only be strings.

The only solution I can currently think of, is to create a pipeline that calls a REST api to get the tenants to update, and then uses the [azure devops api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to queue the actual update process with the correct parameter value. But this feels like a bit of a clunky workaround to accomplish this.

Now my question is, are there any (better?) alternatives to accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help. I was able to use external source (.txt file) to fill array variable in azure pipelines.

#### Working example

```yaml
          # Create a variable
          - bash: |
              arrVar=()
              for images in `cat my_images.txt`;do
                arrVar+=$images
                arrVar+=","
              done;
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=list_images]$arrVar"

          # Use the variable
          # "$(list_images)" is replaced by the contents of the `list_images` variable by Azure Pipelines
          # before handing the body of the script to the shell.
          - bash: |
              echo my pipeline variable is $(list_images)
```

#### Sources (there is also example for matrix)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script

#### Other sources

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script

Comment: Thanks. The problem is I need to run a job per tenant. Creating a matrix based on variables doesn't seem possible, so your solution won't work for me. We sticking to the separate pipeline using the API to queue the actual pipeline with the correct parameter values until we find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

> To accomplish this, we would like to create a job per tenant, so we
> can process tenants in parallel.

Apart from rolling deployment strategy, you can also check [Strategies and Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#strategies).

You can try something like this unless you have to use Runtime parameters:

```
jobs:
- job: Update
  strategy:
    matrix:
      tenant1:
        Someotherproperty1: '1.1'
        Someotherproperty2: '1.2'
      tenant2:
        Someotherproperty1: '2.1'
        Someotherproperty2: '2.2'
      tenant3:
        Someotherproperty1: '3.1'
        Someotherproperty2: '3.2'
    maxParallel: 3
  steps:
      - checkout: none
      - script: echo $(Someotherproperty1).$(Someotherproperty2) 
        displayName: 'Echo something'
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to hardcode the tenants in my pipeline, but the only way to use these kind of strategies is to use runtime parameters, because its the only way to influence the job expansion. Matrix combined with runtime parameters might already make my solution a bit better, but still requires me to first start a different pipeline to be able to call my pipeline with the correct parameters

Comment: I've tested and indeed using matrix makes it a bit better, since now I can control the max parallel jobs being executed. However, I still need some way to fill the tenants parameter (original question). And as far as I know it HAS to be a parameter, because otherwise I cannot expand the matrix correctly

Comment: Here's [one discussion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/880210/allow-type-casting-or-expression-function-from-yam.html) about type casting from object to string. Looks like you can't use someotherProperty in that way.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, but I don't see how this helps me. I need some way to specify runtime parameters within the pipeline itself, not convert objects to strings. I think my solution using the Api is the only way to accomplish what I want unfortunately